# How should I unregister for KVO on self?

Tags: iphone, key-value-observing

I'm trying to use KVO to observe properties on a `UIView` subclass in order to trigger drawing by calling `drawRect:`. In my `initWithFrame:`, I have this:

```
...
self.observedKeysThatTriggerRedraw = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", nil];
for (NSString *aKey in self.observedKeysThatTriggerRedraw) {
    [self observeValueForKeyPath:aKey ofObject:self change:nil context:redrawContextString];
}
...
```

(`redrawContextString` is a constant `NSString` unique to this class)

The KVO notifications are firing as they should, which is triggering the redraw correctly. The problem is unregistering KVO. If I don't unregister, everything runs fine, but I get an exception if I put this at the top of my `dealloc`:

```
for (NSString *aKey in self.observedKeysThatTriggerRedraw) {
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:aKey];
}

self.name = nil;
...
[super dealloc];
```

I get this message in the console and a crash when it gets to the `removeObserver:forKeyPath:`:

> *CoreAnimation: ignoring exception: Cannot remove an observer <MyViewClass 0x5b47210> for the key path "name" from <MyViewClass 0x5b47210> because it is not registered as an observer*

Is there some trick to unregistering KVO when you are observing `self`? Are my observers being unregistered for me be the time `dealloc` is called? I've read in a bunch of places that you shouldn't unregister for KVO in `dealloc`, but I'm not sure where else I can do it when observing `self`.

Comment: you should definitely avoid messaging self in init, dealloc, and other partially constructed/destructed states.

Comment: I think that's a bit like saying "goto is evil". How else would you suggest unregistering for KVO on self? How would you release an auto-synthesized, retained property in dealloc without using `self.property = nil;`?

Comment: @Justin, in `init` you are perfectly safe to message self after `self=[super init]`. In `dealloc` you are perfectly safe to message self before you send `[super dealloc]`. The notable exception is NSManagedObject.

Comment: @Nick Forge the statements are not equivalent. goto produces well-defined behavior.

Comment: The real issue is sending messages that have side effects that will cause problems in a partially constructed/deconstructed state. e.g. calling a property accessor where the property setter is non-standard, especially where it calls other properties/ivars, should be avoided in init/dealloc (unless you're really careful) for pretty obvious reasons. The issue isn't actually just sending messages to self, which is 100% safe to do once you've called `self = [super init]`.

Comment: @Justin messaging self in init or dealloc produces well-defined behaviour also (as long as you've done `self = [super init]`). It's just that you have to be careful/mindful of the subtleties of what you're doing (just like when using `goto`).

Comment: @Nick Forge i do know the reasons to avoid it (after all, i was the one who recommended it). since you understand the consequences: why is there a good reason to avoid practical safety measures which easily lead to UB if ignored? if something goes wrong at this stage you'll be lucky if you escape with nothing or a trivial memory leak. it will only complicate maintenance and introduce/expose bugs as libraries and hardware evolve. not every implementation will be affected, (cont)

Comment: (cont) but some will (assuming you spend a good amount of time developing) - and it's all easily avoided. managing resources here is better than subjecting clients/subclasses to the internals of your objects' construction/destruction. that doesn't make for reusable code.

Comment: @Costique i don't see NSManagedObject as the notable exception. i see it as implementation defined for any object, and implementations are subject to change across releases and platforms. it's safest (imo) to avoid where possible.

Comment: @Justin NSManagedObject is an exception because the docs state "You should typically not override dealloc...", which is an immediate warning to be extremely cautious. Otherwise, messaging self is not dangerous per se, you just have to know what you're doing. Always.

Comment: @Costique it makes no sense to subject clients and subclasses to adhere to 'always know what you're doing' concerning *your* implementation, or to expect them to update their program based on changes to your implementations (unless the error is fatal). this can be easily minimized when initially written. the implementations do change -- functional programs will break as third party libraries are updated. it's a waste of time wrt maintenance for you and for clients. you can't possibly always know what side effects will exist in unpublished, unreleased programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't actually registered the view as an observer with `addObserver:forKeypath:options:context:`. Either you should register self as an observer or (if you don't use KVO in a standard way, manually sending `observeValueForKeyPath...`), you should not try to unregister self as an observer.

Comment: Haha, during some re-writing of my code, I did in fact put `observeValueForKeyPath:...` where `addObserver:forKeyPath:...` should have been. For some reason `observeValueFor…` intuitively seemed like a reasonable method name for starting to observe something.